# Displaying an image from within an Android app?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, filesystems, photo

I have `filepath` which is a String holding the absolute path to an image file.

Is there a way to display the image to the user similar to when they use the Gallery app?

When I looked up solutions to this problem, most of them involved setting an ImageView's bitmap to the bitmap decoded from the file, but I don't want to go this route because the orientations may be different, the size of the picture may not be maximized depending on how it fits within the ImageView, and so on. I basically want to have it displayed full-screen. Or if this *can* be done with an ImageView I'd be curious to know how.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: "similar to when they use the Gallery app?" -- there are ~2 billion Android devices, spread across thousands of device models. There are hundreds of different "Gallery app" implementations across those device models, as device manufacturers and custom ROM developers usually supply their own. There are hundreds, if not thousands, of additional similar apps available on the Play Store and elsewhere. Please do not assume universal behavior amongst all these apps. "Why the triple-downvote?" -- probably the lack of [mcve] showing what you tried and what problems you encountered.

Comment: What this questions is asking for is, how to implement pinch zoom features etc just like gallery app

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an ImageView in your layout that fills the parent

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:id="@+id/your_image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Then you use the Picasso library to load the image by

1/ Inflating the ImageView

```
yourImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.your_image);
```

2/ Loading the image to the ImageView like

```
Picasso.with(context).load(filepath).fit().into(yourImage);
```

Check http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 0):

Use the following library: [TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView)

### Usage:

Place `TouchImageView.java` in your project. It can then be used the same as
ImageView. Example:

```
TouchImageView img = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
```

If you are using TouchImageView in xml, then you must provide the full package
name, because it is a custom view. Example:

```
<com.example.touch.TouchImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```